# File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`gem "bootstrap-sass", '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.6'
gem "compass-rails", "~> 3.0.2"
gem "bourbon"`

`#when I run gem list
bourbon (5.0.0.beta.7, 5.0.0.beta.6, 4.3.4)`

`#when I run bundle show
 * bourbon (5.0.0.beta.7)`

[this is my web page error,but  I have installed bourbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWCXr.png)

Comment: Please copy your code here, you are more likely to get answers that way, also your question will not depend on external sources. Now, for your error, have you added `@import "bourbon";` in your `application.scss`?

Comment: This can help https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/issues/182

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/issues/615#issuecomment-254784661